# FCM Registration token

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, token, registration

I need the values of the registration token I sent to the FCM database from my android app.  How do I access it and where is it stored in the FCM database.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: First create your Android project, and copy the package name from AndroidManifest.xml.
assume package name is  package="com.learn.fbc.cloudmessaging"

Step2: Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/

Click 'Add project'

Set project name

Set Country

and Tap 'Create Project'

Step3: Click 'Add Firebase to your Android app'

Step4(Important step): set package name (in our example, it should be com.learn.fbc.cloudmessaging)

Step5:Click 'Register App'

Step6: Downlod 'google-services.json' to your machine

Step7: copy 'google-services.json' to app/ folder of your project [important step]

Step8. go to project level build.gradle and set

```
dependencies
{
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'     
}
```

Step9. Add following to your app level build.gradle

```
 dependencies
 {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Step10: Sync your gradle

Step11: Extend  FirebaseInstanceIdService class  e.g.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = 
       MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();
 @Override
  public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    Log.d(TAG, "onTokenRefresh: "+refreshedToken);

}

 private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
    Log.d(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
 }
}
```

Step12: Extend FirebaseMessagingService class 
e.g

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
 }
}
```

Step13: declare both services to your manifest file e.g

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->``
</application>
```

Step14: Run your app on your device

Step15: Now you can send push notification from firebase clouding service to test.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet on how you send the registration token to the database would be better. FCM doesn't automatically store the token, you have to implement the saving logic. Can attach it to your user node and always update it inside onTokenRefresh() method. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.e("FCM TokenID:", refreshToken);
    saveToServer(refreshToken);
}

  void saveToServer(){ 
     //Implement save/update logic here

}
```